# Почему не отвечает бот вк на pythonanywhere

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

```
from flask import Flask, request, json

import vk_api
import random

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token="мой токен")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ["POST"])
def main():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    if data["type"] == "confirmation":
        return "код коллбек апи"
    elif data["type"] == "message_new":
        object = data["object"]
        id = object["peer_id"]
        body = object["text"]
        if body.lower() == "штирлиц проверка":
             vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Alles ist sehr normal.", "random_id": random.randint(0)})

    return "ok"
```

собственно вот мой код

Comment: Добавьте деталей. Пишите ли Вы ему в личные сообщения или в беседу, пробовали ли Вы логировать действия бота?

Comment: пишу ему и там, и там. нигде не отвечает. логировать не пробовал.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере ,когда вы заходите  на сайт, то он запускает бота, который соответственно работает некоторое время, а потом засыпает. Значит вам нужно, чтоб кто нибудь посещал ваш сайт ежечасно и соответственно это будет запускать бота. Для этого можно воспользоватся сервисом  UpTimerRobot,которому вы даете ссылку на ваш сайт и он будет отправлять запросы на ваш сайт->Вызывать обработчик main->Вызывать запуск бота вк. Такая технология называется веб-хуком и она бесплатная.

Советую вам загрузить бота не на pythonanywhere,а на replit по замечательной статье на Хабре, которая также реализует все ,что я сказал выше https://habr.com/ru/articles/709314/.Cам загружаю туда ботов и скрипты ,и меня он не подводит).